# Trying to create firebase user in MST(mobx state tree)action

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to create new user in firebase using MST actions.

My code looks something like this:

```
.actions((self => ({
    createUserWithEmailPassword:
        flow(function*(password: string) {
            console.log('creating user');
            yield firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
            console.log('set Persistence');
            const user = yield firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(self.email, password);
            console.log('CREATED USER', user);
            self.uid = user.uid;
        })
}));
```

It does create a user, but it won't go ahead of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` call. (i.e. it will never console 'CREATED USER`)

I also have onPatch console on user, but it also won't show user updating.

I tired to console fake api call

```
let res = yield fetch("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
```

this works perfectly.

Looks like there is something wrong with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: First wrap internals of the `flow(function*(password: string) { })` into `try ... catch` to make sure that it doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work but you can try this as well

```
createUserWithEmailPassword(password: string) {   
  flow(function*() {
            console.log('creating user');
            yield firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
            console.log('set Persistence');
            const user = yield firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(self.email, password);
            console.log('CREATED USER', user);
            self.uid = user.uid;
        })() // <--- check this
}
```

Flow will return a function that you need to call

OR like this

```
createUserWithEmailPassword(password: string) {
        const run = flow(function*() {
            console.log('creating user');
            yield firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
            console.log('set Persistence');
            const user = yield firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(self.email, password);
            console.log('CREATED USER', user);
            self.uid = user.uid;
        })

        run()
}
```